How to make my vuetify 3 nuxt 3 application use the visible viewport
My problem is controlling my Vuetify 3 Nuxt 3 applications scroll behavior. What I want to achieve is the following:

What I actually have is the following:


I want the application to fill out the full viewport, I want a navbar at the top of the application and a navigation-drawer on the left. There should be no scrollbar except if the content of the main area are higher than the areas height. Right now there's 3 scrollbars even though the whole content should fit in the view port.
I tried a lot of things, like setting html and body to width:100vw;height:100vh;, setting heights and overflows of the other nested nodes but until now I can't get the html and body to take up only the visible viewport, there's always a few pixel more at the bottom as you see on my screenshots. I can hide the overflow using overflow: hidden but than I'm not able to scroll the main area on overflow later. Maybe there's an obvious solution but I'm a total beginner in css...

What do you want to achieve exactly? Having a page occupy a whole vertical viewport? Did you inspected it in your browser devtools?

Can you maybe make a [repro] please?

I edited the post, I hope it's clear now. Please get back to me if there's any open questions or more clarification needed.

I couldn't add it as Stack Snippet adding nuxt 3 is a bit more complicated there. Regarding your question, yes I inspected it with devtools and tried a lot of things.

I ran your git project locally on my side. So what's the biggest difference? Because I can pretty much do what you asked for. The topbar is just a little bit smaller but I do not see a lot of different things overall. Otherwise, the rest of the alignment is mostly using flexbox vertically and horizontally to have them in the middle.

I added it to codesandbox as you suggested. The main difference is that there's 3 scrollbars right now. A horizontal and a vertical bar to scroll the html/body and a third scrollbar on v-main which is not even showing completely since it's under the navbar. Also there's no reason that there should be any scrollbar at the moment. I want the current application to fit the whole viewport without anby scrollbars, a vertical scrollbar should only appear if the content of v-main is to high

Also just to mention I have a use case on a different page within the same application where a scroll should only appear on the horizontal axis there the vertical growth is blocked and it's only possible for content to grow on the horizontal axis.

It’s not about the sizes of the bars at all, the first image is created with paint. I just wanted to illustrate that only the main content shall be scrollable and only if the content is too high. Sorry for any misunderstandings, English isn’t my first language and maybe i explained it badly.

I am not sure of the behavior of Vuetify, but removing this works well
html, body {
  /* height: 100vh; */
  /* width: 100vw; */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(34, 34, 143);
}

* {
  /* border: 1px solid #a45abd; */
}

Using those units is quite dangerous, let the page flow.

No this leads to only having one scrollbar on the body but still the page is too big for the viewport and the scroll is not only on v-main if the content is higher than v-main.

You can see the problem better by adding: `html,
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: auto;
background-color: rgb(34, 34, 143);
}
html {
width: 99%;
height: 75% !important;
}
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
#__nuxt {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: #3f3f49;
}

{
border: 1px solid #a45abd;
}` as css.


If you want to hide the scrollbar, you can use this. As for me, I only can scroll in the green container. You should definitely not add a lot of things to html or body regarding sizes, do it inside of your elements. I am also on a laptop MacOS machine, so I might not see some bars but tbh I can only see the one in the green container. I don't know what v-main does but feel free to not use it or reset it's CSS.

Thanks for your effort. But it’s not right to be able to scroll in the green container. It only contains a very small string. It shouldn’t be larger than the viewport at all. The green area should fill the whole remaining body with no scrollbar at all until it has content that is larger than the area

Do you have the same issues outside of Vuetify?

I rewrote my layout and changed css to your solution and it's working now. I can't really tell why. My layout and my app.vue are way more complex then shown in that basic example. they have some server side and some client side only code and i think restructuring it in addition with your css changes helped.

@kSp happy that it helped! Sometimes it can be messy if you have a lot of things stacking up yes. Don't hesitate to try to reproduce the issue somewhere to narrow down the problem and have an easier time solving it.
